# Cannot return null for non-nullable field on API platform and graphql

Tags: symfony, graphql, symfony4, nullable, api-platform.com

I have an "user" entity with an unmapped property like this :

```
namespace App\Entity\User;

// ...

/**
 * @var string
 * @Groups({"readAnnounce", "readUser"})
 */
private $lastUrlImageProfilValid;


/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastUrlImageProfilValid()
{
    foreach ($this->imageProfil as $image){
        if ($image->getIsValid()){
            return $image->getUrl();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

when i call this entity with REST, it work but not with graphql, it return this error:

> Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.lastUrlImageProfilValid

Graphql code :

```
{
  users(
    first: 30,
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        lastUrlImageProfilValid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i set an unmapped property nullable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the property nullable in your PHPDoc:

```php
/**
 * @var null|string
 * @Groups({"readAnnounce", "readUser"})
 */
private $lastUrlImageProfilValid;

/**
 * @return null|string
 */
public function getLastUrlImageProfilValid()
```

Or, in PHP 7.4:

```php
/**
 * @Groups({"readAnnounce", "readUser"})
 */
private ?string $lastUrlImageProfilValid;

public function getLastUrlImageProfilValid(): ?string
```

Comment: It work, i've already try to make the property nullable but i've missed the getter and the cache:clear.

Thank you for your response !

Comment: FWIW when using the explicit type `private ?CustomEntity $customEntity;` I received an error `The property "App\Entity\MainEntity::$customEntity" is not readable because it is typed "App\Entity\CustomEntity"`.  But typing it with the Annotation worked. Not sure why, or if I didn't do something correctly, but figured I'd mention in case it's helpful to anyone. (using PHP 8)